# how to get the camera stream of HoloLens 1

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, computer-vision, hololens

I am currently working on a project with Microsoft HoloLens 1 and i am running in some problems right now. the target of my project is to get a onnx model to run on the HoloLens, to recognize a few different gestures.

To do so i will have to get access to the camera stream to feed my model with. I tried a few different scripts i found eg. on the Microsoft website but none of them worked for me. The [example](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/windowsholographic-photocapture.html) by unity only showed me a purple sqare somehow.

If anyone does have a plan about this problem i would be really happy.

Comment: sorry for the bad link, but it worked for me two days ago .. can't find the page anymore ..

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you want to get the *video stream* in the world where it was captured for your recognizer. The link you provided seems like pointing to a wrong page, but I believe what you are using is Unity’s [VideoCapture](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/XR.WSA.WebCam.VideoCapture.html) API. Unfortunately, with this API you can only save directly to disk as a .mp4 file.

Hence we recommend trying this guide for capturing the video stream: [Locatable camera](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/locatable-camera)?  As this doc says, we use MediaCapture class to capture a video stream with the locatable camera on the HoloLens. Besides, Microsoft provides a GitHub repository [Camera resolution sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraResolution) shows how to do it with this class.